# Representabillity of torsors and exact sequence of group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes, torsors

I've seen the following property used at many places, I don't exactly why it is true.

Let $S$ be a site with an initial object $e$. There is an exact sequence of group objects

$$1 \to F \to G \to H \to 1$$

Assume that:

1. Any $H$-torsor over $e$ is representable.
2. Let $T \to e$ is an $H$-torsor. Any $F$-torsor over $T$ is representable.

Then any $G$-torsor over $e$ is representable.

For this question you can assume that $S$ is the category of $X$-schemes with your favorite Grothendieck topology.

Comment: Every $G$-torsor is an $F$-torsor over an $H$-torsor: If $Y$ is a $G$-torsor, then $Y/F$ is an $H$-torsor, and $Y\to Y/F$ is an $F$-torsor.

Comment: So, $ Y \to Y \setminus F$ is representable by some scheme over $Y \setminus F $. But why does that imply $Y \to X$ is representable by the same scheme?

Comment: Giving a map to $Y$ as an $X$-scheme is the same as giving a map to $Y/F$ as an $X$-scheme, followed by a map to $Y$ as a $Y/F$-scheme.